# Is the voltage supplied by an LCD backlight inverter in a laptop dangerous in any way?

Tags: voltage, inverter, laptop, shock, backlight

It is my understanding that in a laptop, voltage from a low voltage (say 10V) battery can be converted into higher much higher voltages by way of inverter for an LCD display module. Is this voltage dangerous in any way if I were to put a load on the output, such as my wet finger?

I believe these inverters have a high source of impedance and don't supply much current? Yet I was wondering if there would be a circumstance in which one could possibly feel a shock.

Earlier today, as I was typing on my LED backlit Macbook Pro keyboard, I spilled water all over it while simultaneously having accidentally dug a portion of my finger under a key. Although not part of the display, I thought I would have felt something. Why didn't I?

Apologies for the scattered array of questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Macbook parts are relatively well known. The backlight driver IC in a Macbook is an [TI LP8550](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp8550.pdf). This has a maximum output voltage of 40V.
Not that dangerous.

Traditional CCFL backlight however, create a voltage of several thousand volts. And from experience I can tell that this hurts quite seriously when you touch this.
Dangerous.

In order to get shocked there needs to be a path. A wet keyboard battery powered laptop do not form a path. There is a path when you're holding the monitor chassis with left, and touch the inverter with your right palm.

Comment: 40V could still be uncomfortable. and eve with extreme bad luck fatal. (I have read of a 36V shock fatality)

Comment: @Jasen If you puncture yourself with 40 Volt live wires perhaps.

Comment: I see. I assumed getting water under the keys where the lights sit, while touching the keys and chassis would provide a path, am I wrong?

Comment: @Jeroen3 LV DC can be lethal in the right conditions. Because DC does not operate on an oscillating frequency it can stop your heart surprisingly easy. Look it up.

Comment: Someone has probably died from sticking their tongue on a 12V battery. I'm still not sure I would class it as dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here. Firstly yes there can be high voltages even though the power source was a 10V battery. There can even be a reasonable amount of current, at least for a little while from charged capacitors.

So why then didn't you feel anything? Well firstly it's possible the liquid didn't actually penetrate to any active conductors. Then there is the nature of electricity, it prefers to take the lowest impedance path. Water has a very high resistance, so does human skin. Any voltage trying to travel that path will have to drop significantly unless it is backed up by a lot of current.

Water is also going to cause lots of shorts if it does get in. Those shorts, while still having reasonably high resistance are still much lower impedance than going into your hand.

Basically it would be pretty difficult to get a shock from spilling water on a laptop. You really need to directly touch the terminals of something.

Comment: **Pure "de-ionized"** water has a very high resistance, but it becomes conductive very quickly in the presence of ions, which ordinary household water has aplenty.